# ruby: make hash dynamically by currency change

Tags: ruby

tell us a way to make change for that amount of money. Some examples:

```
> chafor(25)
{qa: 1}

> chanfor(41)
{qua: 1, dim: 1, nick: 1, pen: 1}
```

Comment: If my answer was useful, please accept is as the correct answer by clicking the grey checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let's do this the Ruby way. We'll avoid for/next/while looping, and instead we'll create a starting Hash and iterate over it to produce a resulting Hash:

```
class Change
  COIN_VALUES = {quarter: 25, dime: 10, nickel: 5, penny: 1}

  def self.change_for(cents)
    pairs = COIN_VALUES.map do |coin, value|
      number_of_coins = cents / value
      cents = cents % value
      [coin, number_of_coins]
    end
    pairs.to_h
  end
end

>> Change.change_for(44)
#> {:quarter=>1, :dime=>1, :nickel=>1, :penny=>4}
>> Change.change_for(116)
#> {:quarter=>4, :dime=>1, :nickel=>1, :penny=>1}
>> Change.change_for(77)
#> {:quarter=>3, :dime=>0, :nickel=>0, :penny=>2}
```

Let's walk through the logic step by step:

First, we define a constant, as indicated by the variable name (`COIN_VALUES`) in all caps.

Next, we're going to iterate over that constant using `Enumerable#map`. This will allow us to address each key/value pair individually, perform operations on them, and return an Array from those operations.

The `cents` variable stores the number of remaining cents. We use integer division to get the highest integer representing the number of coins for the current coin, then take the modulo to determine how many cents remain after performing that operation.

When we're done, we have an Array of two-element Arrays, which we store in `pairs`. If `cents` is given as 44, it will look like this:

```
[[:quarter, 1], [:dime, 1], [:nickel, 1], [:penny, 4]]
```

By returning `pairs.to_h` we convert `pairs` into a Hash:

```
{quarter: 1, dime: 1, nickel: 1, penny: 4}
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but a few notes: 1. Your class doesn't have any instance methods or instance variables. Did you mean to make it a module? 2. There's really no reason to have `pairs` at all when you can create a Hash directly. 3. Don't forget about [`Numeric#divmod`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod), which combines integer division and modulo into one. https://repl.it/@jrunning/TragicGrotesqueKernel

Comment: @JordanRunning Thanks for the great suggestions. All good points.